# Youtube API Subscribe Event

Tags: javascript, api, events, youtube, subscribe

I used this code ( https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_subscribe_button#Handling_Events ) to fire an event when the user subscribe to my youtube channel, but it works only when the user is already logged in.
If the user is logged out, google ask him to login and after that he'll be subscribed to my channel, but the event will not be fired at all.

There's a way to fire an event when an anonymous user subscribes to my youtube channel?